# Выдает ошибку Page not found в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

При переходе на страницу категории категории выдает ошибку :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', news),
    path('category/<int:category_id>/', get_category)
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import News, Category


def news(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'news': news,
        'title':'Список новостей',
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, template_name='news/index.html', context=context)

def get_category(request, category_id):
    news = News.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    Category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
    return render(request, 'news/category.html', {'news': news, 'categories':categories, 'category':category})
```

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/news/category/2` наверное?

Comment: Такой страницы нету.

Answer (score 3):

В urlpatterns в path у вас в конце url-а стоит слэш (`category/<int:category_id>/`) и так как у вас в конце стоит слэш, то и в адресной строке вы пишете слэш в конце т.е `http://127.0.0.1/news/category/2/`.

А так без слыша Django не находит совпадений по url-ам, т.е вы вбили `http://127.0.0.1/news/category/2`, а такого адреса нет, но зато есть такой: `http://127.0.0.1/news/category/2/`